# Property of compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact metric space.  Let $A$ be a closed subset of $X$ and let $x\in X$ be a point not in $A$.  Show that there exists two disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that one contains $A$ and the other contains $x$.

Now we consider $A$.  Since $A$ is closed it is also compact.  Because $A$ is closed, every sequence of points in $A$ has its limit point in $A$.  Let $\{x_n\}$ be such a sequence.  Let $\{O_n\}$ be a disc of radius $\epsilon_n$ centered at an $x_n.$  We can extract a finite subcover from this open cover that covers $A$.  Let $O=\cup\{O_i\}_1^k.$

Now consider an $x\in (X\setminus O)$.  This is a closed set.  Again, we repeat the argument with open sets.  None of these open sets will contain points of $O$.  Hence another disjoint open set.

Comment: You can't select $x$, it is given. While irrelevant here, it may be the case that $X \setminus O$ is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed then.

Comment: There are a few ways. Here is one that follows an approach similar to the above:  For $a \in A$, choose the open set $B(a, {1 \over 2} d(a,x))$. Note that the closure of this set does not contain $x$.

Comment: Could I do that with a sequence of points in A?

Comment: @emka: How would that help? I think the most straightforward way to to use the definition of compactness directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that any two distinct points in $X$ can be separated by open sets. This is shown as follows -

Let $y,z\in X$ with $y\neq z$. Then $d(y,z)=:r>0$. Then the open balls $B(y,r/2)$ and $B(z.r/2)$ are disjoint open sets where the first one contains $y$ and the second contains $z$.

Now coming to your problem -

For each $a\in A$ there is a pair of disjoint open sets $U_a,V_a$ such that $a\in U_a$ and $x\in V_a$. the collection $\{U_a\}_{a\in A}$ forms an open cover of $A$ and by compactness there are a finite number that cover $A$. Call them $U_1,\cdots,U_n$. Let $V_1,\cdots,V_n$ be the corresponding disjoint open sets containing $x$. Let $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}U_i$ and $V=\bigcap_{i=1}^nV_i$. Then $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets with $A\subseteq U$ and $x\in V$.

---

**Remark** - this proof works for any Hausdorff space $X$ and a compact subspace $A$ of $X$.

Comment: Note that we only need that $A$ is compact, not that $X$ is.